# Convert a string to double

Tags: c#, .net, string, double

I need help converting a string to double with 7 decimals. I have a string `"00000827700000"` and need it converted to 82.77

Tried using String.Format() with {0:N7} without success.

Comment: Is the format *always* like that? With the stars, and the exact number of characters? Are you sure that `double` is the most appropriate type here, rather than `decimal`?

Comment: I've edited my answer based on the edited question. It would really help if you'd clarified this to start with - and answered the other questions posed in comments.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  By the way, having Jon Skeet answer your first question is like having Eric Clapton walk up to you to help when you asked for someone to "teach you a couple chords".  Please heed his advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you *could* use:

```
decimal x = decimal.Parse(text.Substring(0, 7) + "." +
                          text.Substring(7),
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That would actually parse it to 82.7700000, as `decimal` preserves trailing zeroes (to an extent) but maybe that's good enough? It not, you could change the second argument to

```
text.Substring(7).TrimEnd('0')
```

Note that I'd strongly recommend you to at least *consider* using `decimal` instead of `double`. You haven't explained what this value represents, but if it's *stored* as decimal figures which you need to preserve, it smells more like a `decimal` to me.

Comment: well, now I can't write it any clearer than you have done.  I would still use TryParse, but other than that it wouldn't be any different.  Actually, the second argument could just be `text.Substring(7).TrimEnd('0')` now since there is no garbage characters.

Comment: @Chad: I'd only use `TryParse` if it were legitimate for this to be bad data. I expect it's *actually* machine-generated, and I'd be happy with an exception being thrown here just as I would if (say) XML parsing failed. Good point on the Substring call though - editing...

Comment: fair enough, I actually thought of a potentially simpler way, see my edited response.  Not sure which is quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the edit, it could be simplified as

```
var text = "00000827700000";
var x = decimal.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 10000000;
Console.Write(String.Format("{0:N7}", x));
```

Comment: This is the best I can come up with, formats with 7 decimals showing, and converts the value to a proper decimal, rather than leaving it stringly typed

Comment: Yes, that's a good point - I had originally considered dividing, but it was a pain *when the two pieces were separated*. Now it's a very natural answer.